# Checking if jsonb index exists in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We've got an index on table `influencers` called `ind_unique_id`. This is the statement in the migration file:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ind_unique_id ON influencers(((ind->>'id')::TEXT));`

I can see the index looking it up in PgAdmin. However, if I check it via Rails method `index_exists?` it returns `false`:

`Influencer.connection.index_exists?(:influencers, name: "ind_unique_id")`

I also tried passing it as a symbol:

`Influencer.connection.index_exists?(:influencers, :ind_unique_id)`

None of them return true. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You check for the columns you want, not by the name of the index itself.
Like this

```
Influencer.connection.index_exists?(:influencers, :some_column_name)
```

You can also check for multiple columns

```
Influencer.connection.index_exists?(:influencers, [:some_column_name, :some_other_column_name])
```

But there is another method that does what you were trying to do called `index_name_exists?`

```
Influencer.connection.index_name_exists?(:influencers, :ind_unique_id)
```

Docs for [index_exists?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/index_exists%3F)

Docs for [index_name_exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-index_exists-3F)